# Extra padding inside a div

Tags: html, css, padding

I m having problem to determine from where extra padding is added to a div.

The div containing the text "Video Title" has too much padding added to it. Which is very much unwanted. And i have no idea from where this extra padding is coming.

I have added the styles, the html codes and the link to a page using this sample page.

Please have a look, I'm about to go insane.

---

The style --

```
<style type="text/css">
    html *
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    table.video_list
    {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table.video_list td
    {
        padding: 5px;
        width: 33%;
    }

    div.vid_container
    {

        /*float:left;*/
        /*margin-bottom:15px;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-right:15px;*/
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        /*width:242px;*/
        margin: 10px;
        /*width: 300px;*/
    }

    div.vid_container div.duration
    {
        /*background-color:#160A07;*/
        /*background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url(../images/backs/duration_back_58x24.png);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;*/

        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

        background-color: #1b1b1b;
        bottom:27px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        float:right;
        font-size:14px;
        padding:4px;
        position:relative;
        right:2px;
        text-align:center;
        width:50px;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 85);
        opacity: 0.85;
        font-weight: bold;

    }

    div.vid_container div.info_holder
    {
        width: 248px;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
    }

    div.vid_container div.thumb_holder
    {
        width: 244px;
        height: 184px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: solid 1px #323434;
        padding: 1px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    div.vid_container div.thumb_holder img.thumb
    {
        width: 236px;
        height: 176px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: solid 1px #323434;
    }
    div.vid_container a.title
    {
        color:#DBA0AC;
        display:block;
        font-size:14px;
        height:35px;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-decoration:none;
        white-space:pre-line;
        width:248px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
    }

    div.vid_container a.title:hover
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    div.vid_container div.info_holder div.info_text
    {
        margin-top:5px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
    }

    div.vid_container div.info_holder div.time
    {
        color: #ccc;margin-top: 5px;font-size: 90%;
        text-align: left
    }




    /******************************************
        Videos list
    ******************************************/

    .vid_container .site_name
    {
        text-transform: capitalize !important;
    }

    .vid_container img.thumb
    {
        width: 242px !important;
        height: 182px !important;
        border:1px solid #323434 !important;
    }

    /******************************************
        List View
    ******************************************/

    div.vid_container_listview
    {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.thumb_holder
    {
        float: left !important;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.info_holder
    {
        float: left !important;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.info_holder div.title_holder
    {
        min-height:30px;width:600px;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.info_holder div.info_text
    {
        color: #ccc;margin-top: 5px;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.info_holder div.info_text div.site_name
    {
        font-size: 100%;margin-top:15px;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.info_holder div.info_text div.likes_and_views
    {
        font-size: 100%;margin-top:15px;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview div.info_holder div.added_at
    {
        color: #ccc;margin-top: 5px;font-size: 100%;
    }

    div.vid_container_listview a.title
    {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .float_left
    {
        float: left;
    }

    .float_right
    {
        float: right;
    }

    .clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

And the Html:

```
<div class="vid_container">
    <div class="thumb_holder">
        <a href="#" title="Brunette Teen Paige Taylor">
            <img alt="Brunette Teen Paige Taylor" class="thumb" src="empty_thumb.png" norotate="1" />
        </a>

        <div class="duration">30:16</div>
    </div>

    <div class="info_holder">
        <div class="info_text">
            <a class="title" href="#" title="Brunette Teen Paige Taylor">Video Title</a>
        </div>  

        <div class="time">16 days  ago</div>                    

        <div style="color: #ccc;margin-top: 5px;">
            <div class="float_left site_name" style="font-size: 90%;">Youtube</div>
            <div class="float_right" style="text-align:right;padding-right: 2px;font-size: 90%;">1 likes — 140 views</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link to this sample page is: [Sample Page](http://ultrasoftbd.com/stackoverflow/test.html)

Comment: I like the fact that the consensus here is firebug is good. ;-)

Comment: To all thanks for your time and effort to help me :) Gaby's solution solved my problem. But i learned from all your posts! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `div.vid_container a.title` rule

remove the `overflow:hidden` and change the `height:35px` to

```
height:auto!important;
height:35px;
min-height:35px;
```

***UPDATE***

i see ... the problem is that the `.duration` box is positioned relative and so it remains in the flow of the DOM .. that is what takes the space above the `.title`..

you need to set the `.duration` to have `position:absolute` and `margin-top:-27px;` (and remove the `bottom` property

that should take care of all problems..

Comment: add that will have a problem when title is to long. it will push contents below in much lower. which is not what i want :) i want the title to fill the full 242px x 35px space if its too long.

Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: @anjan, ok i see what the problem was .. look at updated answer

Answer (score 2):

According to my Firebug addin, the extra padding is caused by these two properties of the `<a>` element contained in the `<div>`

```
div.vid_container a.title {
    height:35px;
    width:248px;
}
```

Disabling these rules in the css editor removed the extra padding (top and bottom).

**Edit :** It seems that the overflow could also be due to this property on the `<div>` :

```
div.vid_container div.info_holder div.info_text {
    padding-top:1px;
}
```

You can try disabling this rule if it fits your needs better. It will remove the extra padding on the top of the div.
You will however still have extra space on the bottom of the title, which is caused by the height of the `<a>` element, as explained above.

Comment: Hello Thaibault, if i disable these rules i will have another problem. If the video title goes bigger. then it will break down into 3/4 lines. Using firebug just disable these rules and add a long title you will see this problem. Basically to solve this line breaking problem i had to apply height and width along with overflow. So any workaround on that?

Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: @anjan: could you describe what behaviour you want then? Is it the case that you want the title to take up as little space as possible and take up a maximum of what you set in those widths and heights?

Comment: Apply this instead - 
white-space: nowrap;

Comment: @anjan: What result do you expect if the video title is too long ? Can you describe the expected result in your question ?

Comment: @anjan : I found another rule which could be responsible for the extra padding. Check my edit to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all reply :) What i need is the title can be 35px at max and it must fill the whole 242px width, like what i get when i set the overflow.

Comment: @anjan : Did you try the solution described in my edit ? It should behave exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

1. download firefox if you dont have it.
2. install firebug (an addon)
3. open up firebug in firefox and load your page.
4. right click on the div with video title and select inspect element
5. look at the style and computed tabs to see what is affecting the padding.

Comment: sometimes is not that easy even while inspecting

Answer (score 1):

div.vid_container a.title has a height of 35px which is making your link bigger. I believe this is what is causign the extra space you don't expect (found courtesy of firebug in firefox).

**Edit:** Didn't even notice the horizontal padding at first but as Thibault Falise there is just a width in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

according to Firebug (which I would recommend you to use) and checking the link you provided that div has a padding of 1px and a top margin of 5px, as specified in the css. So there is no extra padding in itself.

As suggested, maybe you want to change the size of the a.title (height, width).